# Handle POST file data NodeJS

Tags: node.js

My NodeJS server is attempting to be able to use and store a file that it gets via a POST request, but I can't figure out how to access the file being passed to it via the `req` variable. It looks like the post itself is both being executed and has some data in the request, but I need to **access that POST file as a variable**, how do I do this?

My code:

Node:

```
 ...
 app.post('/imgUpload', function(req, res) {
     console.log(req);
 }
```

React:

```
...
class RyanForm extends React.Component {
  send() {
    const method = "POST";
    const body = new FormData(this.form);
    console.log('sending info: ' + body);  
    axios.post(URLs.imgUpload, body, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>I'm a form.</h1>
        <form ref={el => (this.form = el)}>
          <label>file:</label>
          <input type="file" name="im-a-file" />
        </form>
        <button onClick={() => this.send()}>Send</button>
        <p>Submit me to see what I send to the server.</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

(Node) Server log:

```
We have a compiled contract!
Cuzzo's app running on port 8003!
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: true,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: 
      TCP {
        bytesRead: 492,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: 14,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 0,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::8003' },
     _server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::8003' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idlePrev: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idleStart: 17023,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage: 
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {} } },
  connection: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: 
      TCP {
        bytesRead: 492,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: 14,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 0,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::8003' },
     _server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::8003' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idlePrev: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idleStart: 17023,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage: 
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {} } },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers: 
   { host: '127.0.0.1:8003',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     'content-length': '89231',
     accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36',
     'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryGl0P9Dl4n16OT4aK',
     referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
     'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9' },
  rawHeaders: 
   [ 'Host',
     '127.0.0.1:8003',
     'Connection',
     'keep-alive',
     'Content-Length',
     '89231',
     'Accept',
     'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     'Origin',
     'http://localhost:3000',
     'User-Agent',
     'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36',
     'Content-Type',
     'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryGl0P9Dl4n16OT4aK',
     'Referer',
     'http://localhost:3000/',
     'Accept-Encoding',
     'gzip, deflate, br',
     'Accept-Language',
     'en-US,en;q=0.9' ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  upgrade: false,
  url: '/imgUpload',
  method: 'POST',
  statusCode: null,
  statusMessage: null,
  client: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: 
      TCP {
        bytesRead: 492,
        _externalStream: {},
        fd: 14,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        _consumed: true },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function: socketOnError],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData],
        resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
        pause: [Function: onSocketPause] },
     _eventsCount: 10,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 0,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::8003' },
     _server: 
      Server {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 1,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _pendingResponseData: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::8003' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idlePrev: 
      TimersList {
        _idleNext: [Circular],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _timer: [Object],
        _unrefed: true,
        msecs: 120000,
        nextTick: false },
     _idleStart: 17023,
     parser: 
      HTTPParser {
        '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        '4': [Function: onParserExecute],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        _consumed: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        outgoing: null,
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage: 
      ServerResponse {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {} } },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  next: [Function: next],
  baseUrl: '',
  originalUrl: '/imgUpload',
  _parsedUrl: 
   Url {
     protocol: null,
     slashes: null,
     auth: null,
     host: null,
     port: null,
     hostname: null,
     hash: null,
     search: null,
     query: null,
     pathname: '/imgUpload',
     path: '/imgUpload',
     href: '/imgUpload',
     _raw: '/imgUpload' },
  params: {},
  query: {},
  res: 
   ServerResponse {
     domain: null,
     _events: { finish: [Function: resOnFinish] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: false,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: true,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: true,
     _removedHeader: {},
     _contentLength: null,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: false,
     _headerSent: false,
     socket: 
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 0,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 17023,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     connection: 
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 10,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 0,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 17023,
        parser: [Object],
        on: [Function: socketOnWrap],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular] },
     _header: null,
     _headers: 
      { 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
        'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
        'access-control-allow-headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' },
     _headerNames: 
      { 'x-powered-by': 'X-Powered-By',
        'access-control-allow-origin': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
        'access-control-allow-headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' },
     _onPendingData: [Function: updateOutgoingData],
     req: [Circular],
     locals: {} },
  route: 
   Route {
     path: '/imgUpload',
     stack: [ [Object] ],
     methods: { post: true } } }
```

NPM Packages (Node):

```
var express = require('express')
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var bigInt = require("big-integer");
var fs = require('fs');
var cmd = require('node-cmd');
var qs = require('querystring');
var util = require('util');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
var app = express();
```

Comment: @dkaramazov I updated the question for the packages, one moment on the output

Comment: @dkaramazov req.body was undefined, is that what body-parser supports?

Comment: Yeah, generally I work with JSON, but it supports other formats I believe.

You may need this:
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

If you are purely interested in File Data you'll probably want to use Multer. Sorry, I noticed that you hadn't included body-parser which I thought was a prerequisite.

Answer (score 1):

Send data to server as `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. In server side use `multer` module.

```
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {

    var fileDest = path.join('../uploads/');
    if (!fs.existsSync(fileDest)) {
      mkdirp(fileDest, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          logger.error(err);
          callback(err, false);
        } else {
          callback(null, '../uploads/');
        }
      });
    } else {
      callback(null, '../uploads/');
    }

  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[1]);
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function(req, file, callback) {

    // To reject this file pass `false`, like so:
    var sw = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < config.validMimeTypes.length; i++) {
      if (file.mimetype === config.validMimeTypes[i]) {
        sw = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (sw === 0) {
      logger.error('Not allowed file type sent');
      // return callback(new Error('Only video files are allowed!'));
      return callback('Only ... files are allowed!', false);
    }

    // To accept the file pass `true`, like so:
    callback(null, true);

  },
  limits: {
    fileSize: config.maxUploadSize
  }
});

app.post('/upload', upload.any(), router.uploader);
```